# Как описать LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES для CreateMutexW

Tags: c++, winapi, mql

Проблема возникла при описании структуры являющейся одним из параметров функции CreateMutexW - LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/56b5b350-f4b7-47af-b5f8-6a35f32c1009) Как ее можно описать на С++, используя стандартные типы, не принадлежащие к WinApi ?

**Если кратко выразить мысль, то как правильно описать струтуру *LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* на языке С++ не прибегая к типам WinApi**

Я не разу не пользовался WinApi, но сейчас потребовалось воспользоваться его функционалом. Ситуация следующая, мне нужно импортировать в язык mql5 ряд функций WinApi для созданию мьютекса (https://www.mql5.com/ru/docs/basis/preprosessor/import) Тут во время импорта функций из WinApi подобные структуры описывают сперва. У меня не получается это сделать, поправьте меня если есть ошибка и посоветуйте как сделать правильнее?

Я описываю так:

```
struct LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
  unsigned long  nLength;
  void* lpSecurityDescriptor;
  bool   bInheritHandle;
};

#import "kernel32.dll"
  long CreateMutexW(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES &lpMutexAttributes, bool bInitialOwner, string lpName);
#import
```

В итоге во время импорта программка жалуется именно на эту структуру. Как бы Вы описали ее на C++ ? Mql5 делался приближенно к плюсам, соответственно те кто на плюсах программируют думаю смогут мне помочь...

Comment: @gregzakharov Если бы я писал на плюсах, то делал бы как раз именно так. Но я пишу на другом языке - Mql5 (для создания торговых роботов). Данный язык создавался по образцу плюсов. В нем можно импортировать С функции из скомпилированных библиотек, а так же использовать WinApi. 

И в нем нет возможности подключить <Windows.h> (как минимум без лишних телодвижений не подключишь). Обычно просто импортируют методы, string - иногда вполне замещает char* и т.д. Нужно просто верно описать LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES - именно на него ругается компилятор

Comment: @gregzakharov Иначе говоря, я стыкую два языка

Answer (score 1):

1. LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES - это указатель на структуру SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES. У вас запись `LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES &lpMutexAttributes` выглядит как передача по ссылке, а не указателю (не знаю, есть ли разница в Mql5).
2. Тип BOOL в WinAPI соответствует int, не bool
3. Ну и, обычно при вызове CreateMutex необязательно передавать эту структуру. Можно объявить как int и передавать 0.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно, в итоге погуглив еще немного - я нашел готовое решение того что старался сделать (https://www.mql5.com/ru/code/1835)

Нужно было просто указывать вместо этой структуры - int / long в зависимости от архитектуры.